# How do I setup multiple users to user public_html?

Tags: apache-2.2, permissions

Basically, I want to allow my team to access my website. I want to use vsftp, so far, I followed this guide: http://library.linode.com/security/sftp-jails and I changed the chroot directory to  `ChrootDirectory /srv/www/domain.com`.

As of right now, I created a test user and the user is able to create a  file but not write to other files because it is owned by `www-data:www-data` and almost all the files in there are `755`. I do not know how to setup the permissions properly so my team can read and write files in the public_html. Currently, since no one has access yet, all the files under public_html are `www-data:www-data`. I do not know if I should set it that way, but let me know.

I just want to setup a few accounts with read and write access to all the files under `public_html`, how can I do this?

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/184548/ftp-and-apache-permission-issues

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the users who need write access to the `www-data` group. Then make sure that group is allowed to write to those files:

```
$ chmod -R g+w /path/to/public_html
```

Comment: That is what I was thinking, but I still have 1 problem. If userA creates a new file, then the other users would not be able to write to it because the file is part of the `userA` group

Comment: I didn't know there was a default and primary group. Thanks!