# How to sort Unix users & groups fixed for web production

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, php, ftp, users

I'm running a Linux webserver (apache2) and I'm having problems with modifying files between different users. **The biggest problem is deleting files created by apache/php via FTP, I just get Permission denied.** I've been trying to add the ftp-user and apache to the same group but it won't work.

Here's my setup now:

```
nano /etc/group
```

->

```
root:x:0:
...some rows...
www-data:x:33:ftpdude,root
...more rows...
ftpdude:x:1000:
```

All the files that are created by php have Owner 33, and ftp'd files have Owner 1000.

I even tried

```
www-data:x:33:ftpdude,root,www-data
```

but it had no effect.

Only way I've managed to make the php-created files deletable is to chmod(file, 0777) all those files but I really don't/shouldn't want to do that. What am I not getting right here?

Comment: possible duplicate of [FTP and Apache permission issues](http://serverfault.com/questions/184548/ftp-and-apache-permission-issues)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding ftp-user to www-data group it's ok, but you probably need to change the default umask for apache:

```
# echo umask 002 >> /etc/apache2/envvars
```

Can you provide the output of ls -la of a php-created file?

Comment: Here's one:

-rw-r--r-- 1 www-data www-data 113969 2011-10-16 10:06 IMG_3706.JPG

Comment: Yep, now it's clear that adding the ftp-user to www-data group isn't enough. You should change the default umask from 022 to 002, system-wide in /etc/profile or in some apache-related script, like the startup script or /etc/apache2/envvars.

Comment: Yeah, that did the trick! There wasn't a umask entry in envvars but I created it, restarted apache (don't know if it was necessary) and now it works. Excellent, thanks!