# How to create FTP accounts with webmin?

Tags: linux, debian, ftp

[image]How to create FTP accounts with webmin?

Have tried to follow a couple of examples found via google.com but none of them worked!?

Have added a user under `system > users`

Server: proFTPD on Debian

## edit

```
Shell: /usr/sbin/nologin
Password: Normal password
Primary group: ftpgroup
```

ftp log

```
STATUS:>    [18-10-2011 20:21:29] Connected. Authenticating...
COMMAND:>   [18-10-2011 20:21:29] USER web_onok
        [18-10-2011 20:21:29] 331 Password required for web_onok
COMMAND:>   [18-10-2011 20:21:29] PASS *****
        [18-10-2011 20:21:29] 530 Login incorrect.
```

## conf

```
#
# /etc/proftpd/proftpd.conf -- This is a basic ProFTPD configuration file.
# To really apply changes reload proftpd after modifications.
# 

# Includes DSO modules
Include /etc/proftpd/modules.conf

# Set off to disable IPv6 support which is annoying on IPv4 only boxes.
UseIPv6             off
# If set on you can experience a longer connection delay in many cases.
IdentLookups            off

ServerName          "Debian"
ServerType          standalone
DeferWelcome            off

MultilineRFC2228        on
DefaultServer           on
ShowSymlinks            on

TimeoutNoTransfer       600
TimeoutStalled      600
TimeoutIdle         1200

DisplayLogin                   welcome.msg
DisplayChdir                .message true
ListOptions                     "-la"
ListOptions "" maxdepth 3
ListOptions "" maxdirs 10
ListOptions "" maxfiles 1000

DenyFilter          \*.*/

 <IfModule mod_auth_pam.c>
    AuthPAM off
  </IfModule>

# Use this to jail all users in their homes 
 DefaultRoot            ~

# Users require a valid shell listed in /etc/shells to login.
# Use this directive to release that constrain.
RequireValidShell       off

# Port 21 is the standard FTP port.
Port                21

# In some cases you have to specify passive ports range to by-pass
# firewall limitations. Ephemeral ports can be used for that, but
# feel free to use a more narrow range.
# PassivePorts                  49152 65534

# If your host was NATted, this option is useful in order to
# allow passive tranfers to work. You have to use your public
# address and opening the passive ports used on your firewall as well.
# MasqueradeAddress     1.2.3.4

# This is useful for masquerading address with dynamic IPs:
# refresh any configured MasqueradeAddress directives every 8 hours
<IfModule mod_dynmasq.c>
# DynMasqRefresh 28800
</IfModule>

# To prevent DoS attacks, set the maximum number of child processes
# to 30.  If you need to allow more than 30 concurrent connections
# at once, simply increase this value.  Note that this ONLY works
# in standalone mode, in inetd mode you should use an inetd server
# that allows you to limit maximum number of processes per service
# (such as xinetd)
MaxInstances            30

# Set the user and group that the server normally runs at.
User                proftpd
Group               nogroup

# Umask 022 is a good standard umask to prevent new files and dirs
# (second parm) from being group and world writable.
Umask               022  022
# Normally, we want files to be overwriteable.
AllowOverwrite          on

# Uncomment this if you are using NIS or LDAP via NSS to retrieve passwords:
# PersistentPasswd      off

# This is required to use both PAM-based authentication and local passwords
# AuthOrder         mod_auth_pam.c* mod_auth_unix.c

# Be warned: use of this directive impacts CPU average load!
# Uncomment this if you like to see progress and transfer rate with ftpwho
# in downloads. That is not needed for uploads rates.
#
# UseSendFile           off

TransferLog /var/log/proftpd/xferlog
SystemLog   /var/log/proftpd/proftpd.log

<IfModule mod_quotatab.c>
QuotaEngine off
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_ratio.c>
Ratios off
</IfModule>


# Delay engine reduces impact of the so-called Timing Attack described in
# http://security.lss.hr/index.php?page=details&ID=LSS-2004-10-02
# It is on by default. 
<IfModule mod_delay.c>
DelayEngine on
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_ctrls.c>
ControlsEngine        off
ControlsMaxClients    2
ControlsLog           /var/log/proftpd/controls.log
ControlsInterval      5
ControlsSocket        /var/run/proftpd/proftpd.sock
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_ctrls_admin.c>
AdminControlsEngine off
</IfModule>

#
# Alternative authentication frameworks
#
#Include /etc/proftpd/ldap.conf
#Include /etc/proftpd/sql.conf

#
# This is used for FTPS connections
#
#Include /etc/proftpd/tls.conf

# A basic anonymous configuration, no upload directories.

# <Anonymous ~ftp>
#   User                ftp
#   Group               nogroup
#   # We want clients to be able to login with "anonymous" as well as "ftp"
#   UserAlias           anonymous ftp
#   # Cosmetic changes, all files belongs to ftp user
#   DirFakeUser on ftp
#   DirFakeGroup on ftp
# 
#   RequireValidShell       off
# 
#   # Limit the maximum number of anonymous logins
#   MaxClients          10
# 
#   # We want 'welcome.msg' displayed at login, and '.message' displayed
#   # in each newly chdired directory.
#   DisplayLogin            welcome.msg
#   DisplayChdir        .message
# 
#   # Limit WRITE everywhere in the anonymous chroot
#   <Directory *>
#     <Limit WRITE>
#       DenyAll
#     </Limit>
#   </Directory>
# 
#   # Uncomment this if you're brave.
#   # <Directory incoming>
#   #   # Umask 022 is a good standard umask to prevent new files and dirs
#   #   # (second parm) from being group and world writable.
#   #   Umask               022  022
#   #            <Limit READ WRITE>
#   #            DenyAll
#   #            </Limit>
#   #            <Limit STOR>
#   #            AllowAll
#   #            </Limit>
#   # </Directory>
# 
# </Anonymous>

<GLOBAL>
    ListOptions "-la"
</GLOBAL>

IdentLookups off
UseReverseDNS off

DefaultRoot                  ~
RequireValidShell            off
AuthUserFile                 /etc/proftpd/passwd

# VALID LOGINS
<Limit LOGIN>
   AllowUser webadmin
   DenyALL
</Limit>

<Directory /home/webadmin>
AllowOverride off
   <Limit ALL>
      DenyAll
   </Limit>
   <Limit DIRS READ WRITE>
      AllowUser webadmin
   </Limit>
</Directory>
```

Comment: anyone.....? :)

Comment: Is ProFTPd set up to use user-directories ?
ISTR the default installation is anonymous-only.

Comment: Do the account names need to be 'real' user names - eg bsmith, or can they be a10031, a10032 etc?

Comment: I can't answer any of your questions. I didn't set up the server because I don't know much about linux/unix

Comment: paste /etc/proftpd.conf somewhere so we can see

Comment: updated.........

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about [`working with a service provider's management interface, such as cPanel`](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- System >> Users and Groups >> Create a new user
- Enter the `Username`
- Change Shell to `/sbin/nologin`
- Check on `Normal password` radio button and enter the password
- Change `Existing group` to `ftp`
- *(You may leave all other options at default)*
- Click on the `Create` button and done.

If it doesn't work, post the error message when logging in with new created account.

---

The reason is your `proftpd` config allow only `webadmin` user to login:

```
<Limit LOGIN>
   AllowUser webadmin
   DenyALL
</Limit>

<Directory /home/webadmin>
AllowOverride off
   <Limit ALL>
      DenyAll
   </Limit>
   <Limit DIRS READ WRITE>
      AllowUser webadmin
   </Limit>
</Directory>
```

If you want to grant access to `web_onok` user, try this:

```
<Limit LOGIN>
   AllowUser webadmin
   AllowUser web_onok
   DenyALL
</Limit>
```

Don't forget to restart `proftpd` service to make it take effect.

Comment: have edited my question

Comment: updated answer.

Comment: I love you..! :D

Comment: but how do I set read/write etc access to the user?

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/184548/ftp-and-apache-permission-issues

Comment: when I login with "web_onok" the owner of the files is "webadmin", but I can't find any user or group with that name?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: When I login with "web_onok" (ftp-client) the owner of the files is "webadmin" and all files are read-only.. In webmin under system > users I can't find a user with the name webmin.. So how can I grand write access to the "web_onok" user? I don't know which group "webadmin" is added to

Comment: You may found it at `Local groups` tab. Add `web_onok` to the `webadmin` group with `usermod -a -G webadmin web_onok` and make the files/folders writable by this group `chmod -R g+w /path/to/folder`.

Comment: I can neither find webadmin under Local user nor Local groups?

Comment: Quite strange. Did you check from `/etc/passwd` and `/etc/group`: `$ grep ^webadmin /etc/passwd /etc/group`?

Comment: nothing i `/etc/passwd` and `/etc/group`.. the closest group/user was web_onok in `/etc/passwd`.. else nothing with string `web`

Comment: Where did you see the `webadmin` owner? Show the screenshot or output?

Comment: print screen added :)

Comment: Besides allowing the system users to login, your FTP server also allow to login with virtual users. Take a look at `/etc/proftpd/passwd`.

Comment: Ok, now it gives more sense :) Do I just have to delete the "webadmin" user in `/etc/proftpd/passwd` and delete "webadmin" from `<Limit LOGIN>`?

Comment: `webadmin` user is only allow when executing [DIRS, READ, WRITE](http://www.proftpd.org/docs/howto/Limit.html) in `/home/webadmin` directory. What do you really want?