# A bunch of questions of permissions with a web server (Cherokee)

Tags: permissions, django, file-permissions, cherokee, arch-linux

I'm new with Linux administration and I'm configuring a Cherokee Web Server.

I'm using Archlinux so I have a http user that owns /srv/http. On the other hand I have a user called 'jesus' that is inside the http group.

```
Cherokee is working with user and group http (http:http)
```

So I made some changes to /srv/http. I added permissions to the group to write there and I changed the owner and group like:

```
drwxrwxr-x  3 jesus http 4096 Oct 25 14:00 http
```

It was like:

So now python can write his .pyc files there (I think that cherokee tell python to create that and because cherokee is able to write there).

My questions are: Is this permission stuff correct?
Someone told me that the group shouldn't have write permissions and is better if I have the http folder (and my websites inside) like:

```
drwxr-xr-x  3 http http 4096 Oct 25 14:00 http
```

So cherokee will be able to write inside because http owns the folder.

Meh, I'm confused.

So, what permissions should have my http folder and everything inside it and what user & group should own that?

I just need my personal websites to run without big security issues :P

Thanks!

PS: Maybe this is related. When python creates his .pyc files, they are -rw-r--r--. Is that correct too?

Comment: What purpose the `jesus` user is used for?

Comment: is my user, the user I use for accessing to the system (ssh) and also have a ts3 running. I thought that since the webs are mine, the user would be that one. But I'm wrong right? :)

Comment: Do you need a FTP server for uploading codes to `/srv/http`?

Comment: well, I will need that. So far im using sftp because I picked the vps yesterday and first I'm trying to leave the cherokee perfect for django deployment :)

Comment: No problem with this permisison but the correct way is setup a FTP server and take a look at this: http://serverfault.com/questions/184548/ftp-and-apache-permission-issues

Comment: I want to use pureftpd on my linux and I Don't know if it creates a fpt user or not. I saw that link but I don't understand. Should I create a group for ftp, my user and http and launch my cherokee using that group? and www (and all inside it like) jesus:thegroup or http:thegroup. Im confused. Thanks.

Comment: A FTP server is normally running as `nobody` user/group. You should add `nobody`, `http` to a group and `chgrp` to that group for `/src/http`. The owership should be `http:thegroup` (`http` is the user which web server is running as). Does `jesus` has `sudo` permission?

Comment: (this say about move this to chat). Ok, I created webgroup added jesus, http, nobody and ftp (just in case) to it and now http directory is like (drwxrwxr-x  3 http webgroup 4096 Oct 25 14:00 http). Is that fine and secure? Or should I remove some permission there? jesus has sudo yes. I installed the ftp but jesus have only access to his home so I can't upload to http.

Comment: The 775 permission for document root is OK. No need to add the system user (`jesus`) to `webgroup`. If you want to create some files in this folder, the correct way is switch to `http` user with `sudo su - http -s /bin/bash`.

Comment: I see. So I upload my sites to /home/jesus and from there I move it to http folder using sudo and there I change to http user, change the site to http:webgroup and work with it. Is that correct? :) If so, I have no more questions, so you can put this stuff on an answer to close this :)

Comment: You should create a new user without shell access for `ftp`ing. Instead of "upload and move", you can use `mount --bind`, something like this `mount --bind /srv/http/web1 /home/<ftp_home_folder>/<ftp_user>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> On the other hand I have a user called 'jesus' that is inside the http
> group.
>
> the user I use for accessing to the system (ssh) and also have a ts3
> running. I thought that since the webs are mine, the user would be
> that one.

The system users which has shell access shouldn't be added to the `http` group. To write some testing files in the document root, you can switch to `http` user with:

```
$ sudo su - http -s /bin/bash
```

For the FTP purpose, you had better create a new user without shell access:

```
$ sudo useradd -d /home/ftp/ftpu1 -s /sbin/nologin ftpu1
$ sudo usermod -a -G nobody ftpu1
$ sudo mount --bind /srv/http/web1 /home/ftp/ftpu1
```

or use virtual users.

The correct permission and ownership for the document root should be:

```
drwxrwsr-x 8 http nobody 4096 Oct 17 15:36 /srv/http/
```

Pay attention to the **s** at group execute bit location. It means that this folder is set SGID, the newly created files/folders also have the same group ownership.

Don't forget to set `umask` for the Apache and the FTP server to 002 to make the files/folders created by `http` can be overwrite by `nobody` and vise versa.

Comment: Im looking the new stuff you said but Im confused. The group was webgroup and not nobody, right? (webgroup is for nobody and http too) And the rws umask on the group. I like it. Can I put that on the user so every file will be owned by http by default? And I don't understant the last paragraph. cherokee (im not using apache) creates the files owned by http by default and nobody is in the group.

Comment: You can add `http` to `nobody` group and `nobody` user to `http` group or add both of them to a common group (`webgroup`). What do you mean when you said _"Can I put that on the user"_?

Comment: That's weird, I mean, is not easier to add http and nobody users to webgroup? So, you mean to add http user to nobody group and nobody user to http group and add both groups to webgroup?. With "Can I put that on the user" I meant the 's', something like u+s :P