# Apache permission Problems

Tags: php, apache-2.2, permissions, ftp, mkdir

Ok all my files and folders are set as owner of vsftpd:nogroup. FTP program can upload and create and do everything. But when I use the PHP command mkdir, I get a Permission Denied even though the folder its creating it in is set to chmod 777. IF i set the base folder to user www-data and group www-data, PHP mkdir will work. However, I can't use FTP to delete or upload to that folder.

/uploads is base folder.

I use PHP mkdir to create a directory in there:

```
if (!is_dir($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/uploads/" . $_REQUEST['clientID'] . '/video/')) {
    @mkdir($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/uploads/" . $_REQUEST['clientID'] . '/video/', 0777);
}
```

If */uploads* is vsftpd:nogroup then PHP mkdir will give a Permission Denied error.

If */uploads* is www-data:www-data then PHP mkdir WILL work, but I cant continue to FTP anything in that folder that was just created.

If */uploads* is vsftpd:www-data then PHP mkdir will give a Permission Denied error.

How can I create a directory with PHP and still be able to access it via FTP?

Comment: Put the WWW user and the FTP user in a group and give that group ownership of the directory. This is not a programming question, it's a UNIX/system administration question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [FTP and Apache permission issues](http://serverfault.com/questions/184548/ftp-and-apache-permission-issues)

Answer (score 0):

This should add your user to the www-data group. As long as files created by www-data are made with a group write you should be able to modify or delete them

sudo adduser vsftpd www-data