# Permission error in Linux directory creation

Tags: linux, ubuntu, permissions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [FTP and Apache permission issues](https://serverfault.com/questions/184548/ftp-and-apache-permission-issues)

i want to create a directory with full permissions (also applies to its "sub folders"). I am using following command:

```
  sudo chmod 777 -R /opt/www
```

It sets permissions to existing folder and subfolders only. I want to make it applicable to new files/folder also so that I don't need to type in the same command again and again for new files and folders

Answer (score 5):

NEVER `chmod 777`. What you need are `umask`, `SUID`, `SGID`.

Comment: whats the complete syntax?

Comment: @sandbox - Please familiarize yourself with *man pages* (`man man`) - ServerFault is not a "gimmeh t3h c0dez" kind of site -- If you have a question about syntax or usage the man page for the command in question should be the first place you look (but feel free to ask additional questions if you find the manual unclear)